# Parsing json file using Python, which is having multiple pairs with same value

Tags: python, json

I Am new to python and I have a json response (see below). I wanted to search for the value of id for `site1` and also list all the values of id.

```
{ "listSiteResponse" : { "count":4 ,"site" : [  {
  "id": "28e4cc3f-d0c2-46f4-9e0c-b532fd148292",
  "simpleid": 15,
  "name": "Site1",
  "description": "Blr1",
  "location": "Bangalore1",
}, {
  "id": "188d4b47-1955-43e1-82a8-7ccedcfc636b",
  "simpleid": 16,
  "name": "Site2",
  "description": "Blr2",
  "location": "Bangalore2",
}, {
  "id": "63fab512-4b52-4038-8a3b-4632f1911dca",
  "simpleid": 17,
  "name": "Site3",
  "description": "Blr3",
  "location": "Bangalore3",
}, {
  "id": "2db3949a-ba2f-4e93-85b5-24a995fa3d99",
  "simpleid": 18,
  "name": "Site4",
  "description": "Blr4",
  "location": "Bangalore4",
} 
}}
```

I tried the following script for listing ids but I get an error:

```
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('logs/CurrentSitesList.txt')

data = json.load(json_data)
test=data["listSiteResponse"]["site"]["id"]
```

Comment: Please review my changes to make sure I didn't lose the intent of your post. What is the error your script gives?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the `id` of the `site` of the `listSiteResponse`, but the problem is that `data["listSiteResponse"]["site"]` is a `list` not a single item, and you cannot get the `id` of a list; instead, you can get the `id` of all items, or just one item, in that list:

```
ids = [x["id"] for x in data["listSiteResponse"]["site"]]
```

Which, without using the compact list comprehension syntax, is equivalent to:

```
ids = []
for site in data["listSiteResponse"]["site"]:
    ids.append(site["id"])
```

But the list comprehension syntax is, IMO, much more readable (as well as obviously shorter).

Also, when you open a file, you should make sure it gets closed; so you can either use `try-finally` or better yet:

```
with open('logs/CurrentSitesList.txt') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

**P.S.** you might want to read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) :)

**UPDATE:** as per the additional comment by the OP in the comments:

given the list of sites

```
sites = data["listSiteResponse"]["site"]
```

you might want to find a site with a given ID

```
site = [x for x in sites if x["id"] == <SPECIFIC_ID>].pop(0, None)
# site will contain either the found object, or None
```

or find the ID of a site that matches a criterion (generalizing the previous snippet)

```
site = [x for x in sites if x["name"] == "Site 1"].pop(0, None)
site_id = site["id"] if site else None
# site_id will contain the ID of the matching site, None otherwise
```

but in the second case, depending on the criteria, you might get multiple results, so adapt your code accordingly if that's the case.

For a more thorough Python tutorial, see the freely available book **[Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org)**.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Instead of storing this value and  comparing using if statement is there a way we can find the id if we give some other unique id . For eg to find the id if we give search parameter as site1